# onChange event doesn't work as expected when <select> in React

Tags: javascript, select, onchange, reactjs

I have a table that displays info about the ticket when editing. The tickets are received from an API as an object, in my case is `data` (eg. `apiUrl: {tickets: '/api/tickets'}`). `data` contains all the default states of the ticket, such as: priority, status and type. All the API data is managed in the `TicketForm` component. See the component code bellow:

```
class TicketForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleSelectChange = this.handleSelectChange.bind(this);
        this.save = this.save.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            apiUrl: {tickets: '/api/tickets'},
            data: {
                id: '',
                ticket: '',
                key: '',
                priority: {
                    id: "",
                    name: ""
                },
                status: {
                    id: "",
                    name: ""
                },
                type: {
                    id: "",
                    name: ""
                }
            },
            priority: [],
            status: [],
            type: []
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        //Getting the JSON from APIs
    }

    save() {
        //Saving/Updating data to server
    }

    handleSelectChange(e) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state[e.target.name].length; i++) {
            if (this.state[e.target.name][i].id == e.target.value) {
                this.state.data[e.target.name] = this.state[e.target.name][i];
            }
        }
        this.setState({data: this.state.data});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <table className="table table-striped">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>Priority:</th>
                    <td>
                        <SelectForm
                            onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
                            name="priority"
                            options={this.state.priority}
                            selected={this.state.data.priority.name}/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Status:</th>
                    <td>
                        <SelectForm
                            onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
                            name="status" options={this.state.type}
                            selected={this.state.data.type.name}/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Type:</th>
                    <td>
                        <SelectForm
                            onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
                            name="type"
                            options={this.state.status}
                            selected={this.state.data.status.name}/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        )

    }
}
```

I want to edit this info when clicking on the element, afterwards I render a `<select>` with a few options that are received from a API as an array, with different options that can be applied for the fields: priority, status and type.  This is a different API then the above (eg. `apiUrl: {tickets: '/api/tickets/type'}`). After choosing the `option`, I get the data from the chosen object and replace it, in the initial `data` object. See the `SelectForm` component bellow:

```
export default class SelectForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            edit: false
        };
    }

    editProject() {
        this.setState({edit: true});
    }

    blurProject() {
        this.setState({edit: false});
    }

    handleChange(e) {
        if (this.props.onChange) {
            this.props.onChange(e);
        }
    }

    renderForm() {
        return (
            <select
                className="form-control"
                name={this.props.name}
                onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
                onBlur={this.blurProject.bind(this)}>
                {(Array.isArray(this.props.options) && this.props.options.length > 0) ? this.props.options.map(option => {
                    return (
                        <option key={option.id} value={option.id}>{option.name}</option>
                    )
                }) : (<option>No Options Found</option>)}
            </select>
        )
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.edit) {
            return this.renderForm();
        } else {
            return (
                <p onClick={this.editProject.bind(this)}>{this.props.selected}</p>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to handle the changes events. When choosing other option from the select to set the states as per the one chosen and display the new state in the field after I have selected the option.

I thought that I achieved this, but somehow the fields are acting strange between them. Priority seems to work fine, but whenever I choose a option from type, the status it changes without even touching it and vice versa.

I cannot understand what is the problem, please have a look in the `handleSelectChange()` function logic, and tell what am I doing wrong, or some solutions for this issue.

### UPDATE:

Found in the answers, that this documentation about [Immutability Helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) will help. I have tried to use one example from the link, but I get the same result. Please have a look at the code and let me know if I'm doing it right:

```
handleSelectChange(e) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.state[e.target.name].length; i++) {
        if (this.state[e.target.name][i].id == e.target.value) {
            var newState = update(this.state, {
                data: {
                    [e.target.name]: { $set: this.state[e.target.name][i] }
                }
            });
        }
    }
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

Comment: Is the onChange event that you're passing into SelectForm not keeping it's scope? Maybe try binding it -- onChange={this.handleSelectChange.bind(this)}

Comment: @hootstheowl the events are working fine, except the data after setState is handled in a weird way.

Comment: "whenever I choose a option from type, the status it changes without even touching it and vice versa." what does this mean. and what are you trying to achieve with `handleChange()`

Comment: The problem is not in `handleChange()`, anyway with this event I'm listening to the child component. The problem is in `handleSelectChange()`, the `setState` is not working as expected. I have to change each field independently, but they are interacting with each other in a weird way. If I change one field, the others are changing automatically, but that is not right.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [immutable helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html) or create new object like this:

```
this.setState(Object.assign({}, this.state, newState))
```

**UPD:**
try to do something like this:

```
handleSelectChange(e) {
  const data = Object.assign({}, this.state.data)

  data[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < data[e.target.name].length; i++) {
      if (data[e.target.name][i].id == e.target.value) {
          data[e.target.name] = data[e.target.name][i];
      }
  }

  this.setState({ data });
}
```

Comment: I will read the documentation and see how this must be implemented, but meanwhile can you please share more details on how this should work? I would appreciate. Cause I'm a little confused right now.

Comment: I've tried your example, still having the same issue, now is a little bit worst then it was. There shouldn't be a newState as well?

Comment: I read the documentation about Immutability Helpers that you provided, tried to implement it in my case. But I'm still having the same issue. Can you please have a look at the update above, am I doing it right?

Answer (score 0):

Try and implement the `handleSelectChange()` like this with `setState()` defined inside the for loop. Since you want to set state data value you can't do it like `this.state.data[e.target.name] = this.state[e.target.name][i];` you need to use `setState()`

```
handleSelectChange(e) {
            this.state.data[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
            var self = this;
            for (var i = 0; i < this.state[e.target.name].length; i++) {
                if (this.state[e.target.name][i].id == e.target.value) {
                    self.setState({data: {[e.target.name]: this.state[e.target.name][i]}});

                }
                self.setState({data: self.state.data});
            }

        }
```

Comment: I have tried this method before, but it doesn't work for me. Thanks anyway for the input.

Comment: @VadimBadea what problem do you face with this approach.

Comment: Well from my point of view, this line: `self.setState({data[e.target.name] :  this.state[e.target.name][i]});` has a wrong syntax. I think what you meant is to write it like this: `self.setState({data: {[e.target.name]: this.state[e.target.name][i]}});` That solve the syntax, but not the problem. With this ex, I choose to change a priority the status and type disappear. I'm trying to set the states for each field individually, not depending on each other. The syntax in my initial snippet it seems to work only on first element not on the others. Hope this gives you more details about the issue.